# oracle cloud service user - cant log back in or use sudo anymore

Tags: sudo, oracle

Im using oracle cloud services
My issue started that i couldnt start a program, then i got to know that the problem was root being the owner. So I needed to change to ubuntu:ubuntu throught command sudo chown ubuntu:ubuntu (path). It worked then i wanted to apply to all files and directories in that directory so I ran command sudo chown - Rubuntu:ubuntu / without fully knowing what Im doing. So in the process it got out of the file and changed everything from root:root to ubuntu:ubuntu changing file in bin/root/sudo(not sure the path) to ubuntu:ubuntu and i couldnt use sudo command anymore as user. I read that I needed to connect as root to change it back so i closed the session and tried logging in as root by root@ip but connection denied. So i tried to check in filezilla - connection lost. Tried to connect through putty as ubuntu again but connection denied. Please do you know the solution. Thanks

Comment: The solution would be reinstall. From the info you have given there is no clue what directories or why you did what you did.